# Web Config Transform not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, slowcheetah, web-config-transform

In a .NET MVC 3.0 Application I have the following configuration in `appSettings`:

## web.config

```
<appSettings>
<add key="SMTPHost" value="mail.domain.com"/>
    <add key="SMTPUsername" value="user@gmail.com"/>
    <add key="SMTPPort" value="25"/>
    <add key="SMTPPwd" value="mypassword"/>
    <add key="EmailFrom" value="notific@gmail.com"/>
</appSettings>
```

For debugging, I have the following configuration transform defined:

## web.Debug.config

```
<appSettings>
    <add  key="SMTPPort" value="58" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
</appSettings>
```

And I run the application in debug mode, but my SMTP port is still taking the value from the `web.config`, not `web.Debug.config`.

Can anyone suggest what could be wrong in this configuration?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

The Web.config transforms are only applied as part of a publish operation.

If you wish this to be done as part of an `app.config` build operation, then you can use the SlowCheetah - XML Transforms Visual Studio plugin:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5

Comment: wow took me 2 hours to find this answer.  Thanks for posting it I would have been pulling my hair out.

Comment: It seems that in Visual Studio 2015 **(Web).config transforms** are now a built-in feature, so you no longer need SlowCheetah. But the built-in transforms will only apply if you publish the application, not if you run it. You can look **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17336009/1016343)** how I solved it.

Comment: Not sure why to use this while @komsky's answer provides a simple and clean solution.

Comment: SlowCheetah is great, but from their own documentation: "For web projects the files are transformed when you publish or package your application." In other words, not while debugging.

Answer (score 37):

**Visual Studio (2010 - 2019)** does unfortunately **not** directly support it while you are debugging, it is only intended for publishing - even with the extension SlowCheetah (marked answer) it does not work for me (only for projects using app.config rather than web.config).

**Note** that there is  a **workaround** [described at codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/255781/Web-Config-Transformations-when-Debugging).

It describes how to modify the .msproj file to overwrite the current web.config by the transformed version.

I will first describe that workaround as **Option 1**, but I have recently found out another **Option 2**, which is easier to use (so you may scroll down to option 2 directly if you like):

---

**Option 1:** I have added the instructions taken from the original **codeproject article** (see the link above), because the screen shots there are already gone, and I don't want to lose the entire information:

VS.Net doesn't do any transforming when you are developing and just debugging your local environment. But there are some steps you can do to make this happen if you want.

- First, create the configurations you want in **VS.Net**, assuming the default debug and release are not enough for what you are trying to accomplish.
- Right click on your `web.config` and select **Add Config Transforms** - this will create a dependant transformation config for each of your configurations defined.
- Now you can rename your `web.config` to `web.base.config`.
- Add a `web.config` to your project. It doesn't matter what is in it because it will get overwritten every time we do a build but we want it part of the project so **VS.Net** doesn't give us the *"Your Project isn't configured for Debugging"* pop-up.
- Edit your **`.csproj` Project File** and add the following `TransformXml` task to the AfterBuild target. Here you can see I will be transforming the `web.base.config` file using the `web.[configuration].config` and it will save it as `web.config`. For details, please check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942158.aspx#Anchor_13) Microsoft Q&A, and for instructions how to extend the build, look [there](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724.aspx).

---

**Option 2:**

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21517589/1016343) answer, I have developed a simple console app, TransformConfig.exe (in C# 6.0 syntax):

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform;

namespace TransformConfig
{

  class Program
  {
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myDocumentsFolder = $@"C:\Users\{Environment.UserName}\Documents";
        var myVsProjects = $@"{myDocumentsFolder}\Visual Studio 2015\Projects";

        string srcConfigFileName = "Web.config";
        string tgtConfigFileName = srcConfigFileName;
        string transformFileName = "Web.Debug.config";
        string basePath = myVsProjects + @"\";
        try
        {

            var numArgs = args?.Count() ?? 0;
            if (numArgs == 0 || args.Any(x=>x=="/?"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nTransformConfig - Usage:");
                Console.WriteLine("\tTransformConfig.exe /d:tgtConfigFileName [/t:transformFileName [/s:srcConfigFileName][/b:basePath]]");
                Console.WriteLine($"\nIf 'basePath' is just a directory name, '{basePath}' is preceeded.");
                Console.WriteLine("\nTransformConfig - Example (inside PostBuild event):");
                Console.WriteLine("\t\"c:\\Tools\\TransformConfig.exe\"  /d:Web.config /t:Web.$(ConfigurationName).config /s:Web.Template.config /b:\"$(ProjectDir)\\\"");
                Environment.ExitCode = 1;
                return 1;
            }

            foreach (var a in args)
            {
                var param = a.Trim().Substring(3).TrimStart();
                switch (a.TrimStart().Substring(0,2).ToLowerInvariant())
                {
                    case "/d":
                        tgtConfigFileName = param ?? tgtConfigFileName;
                        break;
                    case "/t":
                        transformFileName = param ?? transformFileName;
                        break;
                    case "/b":
                        var isPath = (param ?? "").Contains("\\");
                        basePath = (isPath == false)
                                    ? $@"{myVsProjects}\" + param ?? ""
                                    : param;
                        break;
                    case "/s":
                        srcConfigFileName = param ?? srcConfigFileName;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            basePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(basePath);
            if (!basePath.EndsWith("\\")) basePath += "\\";
            if (tgtConfigFileName != srcConfigFileName)
            {
                System.IO.File.Copy(basePath + srcConfigFileName,
                                     basePath + tgtConfigFileName, true);
            }
            TransformConfig(basePath + tgtConfigFileName, basePath + transformFileName);
            Console.WriteLine($"TransformConfig - transformed '{basePath + tgtConfigFileName}' successfully using '{transformFileName}'.");
            Environment.ExitCode = 0;
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var msg = $"{ex.Message}\nParameters:\n/d:{tgtConfigFileName}\n/t:{transformFileName}\n/s:{srcConfigFileName}\n/b:{basePath}";
            Console.WriteLine($"TransformConfig - Exception occurred: {msg}");
            Console.WriteLine($"TransformConfig - Processing aborted.");
            Environment.ExitCode = 2;
            return 2;
        }
    }

    public static void TransformConfig(string configFileName, string transformFileName)
    {
        var document = new XmlTransformableDocument();
        document.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        document.Load(configFileName);

        var transformation = new XmlTransformation(transformFileName);
        if (!transformation.Apply(document))
        {
            throw new Exception("Transformation Failed");
        }
        document.Save(configFileName);
    }

  }
}
```

Ensure that you add the DLL `"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll"`as a reference (this example applies to VS 2015, for older versions replace the `v14.0` in the path by the appropriate version number, e.g. `v11.0`).

For **Visual Studio 2017,** the naming schema for the path has changed: For example, for the enterprise version it is here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web`. 
I assume that for the professional version you need to replace `Enterprise` in the path by `Professional`. If you're using the preview version, additionally replace `2017` by `Preview`.

Here's an overview how the path has changed for different versions of Visual Studio (if you don't have the Enterprise version you might need to replace `Enterprise` by `Professional` in the path):

> **VS Version**        **Path (for `Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll`)**
>   2015                  `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web`
>   2017                  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\`
>                            
>   `Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web`
>   2019                  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\`
>                            
>   `Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\Web`

Compile it and put the .exe file into a directory, e.g. `C:\MyTools\`.

**Usage:**
You can use it in your **post build event** (in **project properties**, select **Build Events**, then edit the **Post-build event command line**). Commandline parameters are (example):

> "C:\MyTools\TransformConfig.Exe" /d:Web.config /t:Web.$(ConfigurationName).config /s:Web.Template.config /b:"$(ProjectDir)\"

i.e. first the name of the config file, followed by the transform config file, followed by an optional template config, followed by the path to your project containing both files.

I have added the optional template config parameter because otherwise your original complete config would be overwritten by the transform, which can be avoided by providing a template.

Create the template by simply copying the original Web.config and name it Web.Template.config.

**Note:**

- If you prefer, you can also copy the `TransformConfig.exe` file to the Visual Studio path mentioned above where the `Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll` resides and refer to it in all your projects where you need to transform your configs.
- For those of you who are wondering why I added `Environment.ExitCode = x;` assignments: Simply returning an int from Main did not help in the build event. See details [here.](http://geekswithblogs.net/dchestnutt/archive/2006/05/30/80113.aspx)
- If you're publishing your project and you're using a Web.Template.config, ensure that you did a **rebuild** on your solution with the right configuration (usually Release) before you publish. The reason is that the Web.Config is overwritten during debugging and you might end up transforming the wrong file otherwise.

Comment: Looks like the CodeProject post is pooched. He used screenshots for his code samples, and now since his blog's down, they're lost to history.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the screenshots are gone. But at least the article text is still there, describing the approach. I have added the text description to my answer to avoid losing it.

Comment: True, maybe one can try to contact the author James Coleman at codeproject to fix it there. Not sure if he is still active there, though. @ThomasTeilmann

Comment: I think this might be similar to what was in the lost screenshots.  Seems to achieve the same basic result.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6437192/1003916

Comment: You can access the link with screenshots via web.archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20120728000945/http://ledtalks.posterous.com/webconfig-transformations-when-debugging

Comment: There is a big downside to implementing a .base.config file that overwrites the real .config file for .NET Framework projects: the process of installing or removing NuGet packages modifies the real .config file, not your .base.config file. You will need to manually copy over any changes effected by package management, such as BindingRedirects, and you will need to do so before you hit "build", because that will overwrite them with the .base.config file.

Comment: @Corrodias - That is true, and unfortunately there is no simple solution for that "out of the box" available. The only thing I could think of is to extend the tool TransformConfig.exe to synchronize that - but I am afraid this would also have downside effects.

Answer (score 29):

Answering your question isn't simple, because it poses a problem - if you want to transform Web.config with Web.debug.config - where transformation effect should be stored? In Web.config itself? This would overwrite transformation source file! Probably that's why Visual Studio doesn't do transformations during builds.

Previous Matt answer is valid, but you might want to mix them to have generic solution that works when you actually change active solution configuration from debug to release etc. Here's a simple solution:

1. Create your config transformations for configurations (Debug, Release, etc)
2. Rename `Web.config` file to `Web.base.config` - transformations should automaticly rename accordingly (`Web.base.Debug.config`, etc)
3. Add following **transformWebConfig.proj XML file** to your project folder:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="TransformWebConfig" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
  <Target Name="TransformWebConfig">
    <TransformXml Source="Web.base.config" Transform="Web.base.$(CurrentConfig).config" Destination="Web.config" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

3. Navigate to your project properties, choose **Build Events** and add following content to **Post-build event command line**:

```html
@if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\12.0\bin" set PATH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\12.0\bin;%PATH%
msbuild $(ProjectDir)transformWebConfig.proj /t:TransformWebConfig /p:CurrentConfig=$(ConfigurationName) /p:TargetProjectName=$(TargetPath)
```

Now, when you build your solution, a Web.config file will be created with valid transformations for active configuration.

Comment: Cleanest and best answer. Some questions: 1. Why the XML validations says that the TransformXml elemnt is invalid within the Target element? (the build works BTW). 2. Now that this generates the real Web.Config, I still add the Web.Config to the project. Now any time I switch between Debug/Release, the web.config will change, but I don't necessarily want to commit that all the time into the source repo.

Comment: 1. Can't really tell how VS validates this XML with schema, but this warning is common, so you can ignore it.
2. It depends on what repo are you using, but you can for example use git.ignore file entry.

Comment: This worked well for me -- just changed the 12's in the build-event and proj file to the current version.  

For the post-build event I used:
`'"$(MSBuildBinPath)\msbuild.exe" $(ProjectDir)TransformWebConfig.proj /t:TransformWebConfig /p:CurrentConfig=$(ConfigurationName) /p:TargetProjectName=$(TargetPath)`

and updated `v12.0` to `v14.0` in the .proj file.

Comment: For VS 2017 modify every `12.0` to `14.0`

Comment: If your project contains spaces you need to wrap `$(ProjectDir) with ""  @if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\14.0\bin" set PATH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\14.0\bin;%PATH%
msbuild "$(ProjectDir)transformWebConfig.proj" /t:TransformWebConfig /p:CurrentConfig=$(ConfigurationName) /p:TargetProjectName="$(TargetPath)"`

Comment: 1)don't forget to  include  the generated web.config into web project, or , it will not copy to target folder after published.  2) if the build server lack of these two files, just copy them to the server "Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks","Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform"

Comment: the command line should placed in  Pre build, not post build for deployment, to ensure the  web.config  copyed to deploy target is the nearest build one.

Comment: should also add transform configration file to Web.Config(web.release.congif/web.debug.config), or it won't transform when build&deploy with  msbuild.exe commandline  tool.

Comment: there is another risk:   changes on web.config, nuget package updated, iis configuration changed etc., will be overwrited by the "transformed" file from web.[configuration].config without any warning.

Comment: Update for Visual Studio 2022: `@if exist "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin" set PATH=%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin;%PATH% 
msbuild "$(ProjectDir)TransformWebConfig.proj" /t:TransformWebConfig /p:CurrentConfig=$(ConfigurationName) /p:TargetProjectName="$(TargetPath)"`. Do anyone have any ideas how to modify this script so it don't need to be changed on each new VS update?

Comment: Those with Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition, MSBuild is in `c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin` and the Tasks.dll is `c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll`

Answer (score 9):

for VS 2017 I found the answer [here](https://gist.github.com/EdCharbeneau/9135216) not sure why nobody has referenced it above as it appears to be a very popular solution.  Very easy too.  Make sure you see the comment from IOrlandoni on Mar5 2019 for making it work in VS 2017 and all versions.

Basically its a two stepper.  First, you edit the .csproj file, appending the code below.  Second, you create a new web.base.config configuration and copy the existing web.config there.  After doing that any build will overwrite your web.config with your desired transformation.

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <TransformXml Source="Web.Base.config" 
        Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="Web.config" />
</Target>
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer, but IMO it's missing a trick. If you change `Web.config` from `Content` to `None` then you can use `Source="Web.config" Destination="$(TargetPath).config"` (or perhaps for some types of project, `Destination="$(TargetDir)Web.config"`). I also moved the transform to `AfterBuild`, since it no longer needs to be done before files are copied.

Comment: Ok, actually that doesn't work because for some reason I can't configure it to run from `bin`.

Answer (score 6):

Your immediate question has been answered - the explanation is that the transform is applied on publish, not on build.

However, I think that it does not offer a solution on how to achieve what you want to do.

I have been struggling with this exact problem for a few days now, looking for a way to keep web.config clean and set all keys that vary depending on environment in the respective transform files. My conclusion is that the easiest and most stable solution is to use debug values in the original web.config, that way they are always present when you do debug runs in Visual Studio.

Then create transforms for the different environments you want to publish to - test, integration, production - whatever you have. The now built-in functionality to transform web.config files on publish will suffice for this. No need for SlowCheetah or editing build events nor project files. If you have only web projects that is.

Should you wish to, you could also have the web.debug.config file in your solution, just to keep a separate file with all the values pertaining to the development environment. Be sure to comment in it that the values are not applied when running in Visual Studio though, in case someone else try to use it for that purpose!

Answer (score 4):

To make the transform be done at build time:

Exclude the web.config (+ web.*.config) from your project.
Then rename the files on disk as follows

- web.config => Web.Template.config
- web.Release.config => Web.Transform.Release.config
- web.Debug.config => Web.Transform.Debug.config

Add the web.config to your gitignore and commit the changes so far.

Finally, in a text editor add the following to the project file.

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <TransformXml Source="Web.Template.config" Transform="Web.Transform.$(Configuration).config" Destination="Web.config" />
  </Target>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Web.config" />
    <None Include="Web.*.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Now whenever you build the project the Web.Template.config will be transformed by Web.Debug.Transform.config into Web.config if you selected the Debug configuration in Visual Studio. Same for Release.

When Web.config is generated for the first time you may need to restart Visual Studio after the build and then build again to have Visual Studio recognize the generated web.config.

This approach was tested with an ASP.NET (not Core) project on Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Sounds cool. Will give a try

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had the same problem with a older *web.config* file based on .NET Framework 2.0. The solution was simply remove the web.config's namespace (*xmlns* attibute in *configuration* root node):

BEFORE: `<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">`

AFTER: `<configuration>`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's a extension for Visual Studio 2015

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/05bb50e3-c971-4613-9379-acae2cfe6f9e

This package enables you to transform your app.config or any other XML file based on the build configuration

Comment: SlowCheeta is a not a new one. it has been there for a long time. Their 1.1 release was in 9/8/2011

Comment: @HaBo Thank you for your attention, i removed `new` world as sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Octopus Deploy](https://octopus.com/purchase) (Community edition is free) and let it transform the `web.config` for you. Steps:

1. [Set up Octopus to deploy your web application](https://octopus.com/docs/deploying-applications/iis-websites-and-application-pools)
2. Make sure your `Web.Release.config` has the `Build Action` property set to `Content` just like your main `web.config` file.

That's it! Octopus will do the rest without any special config. A default IIS Web Site deploy will do this out of the box:[image]

Comment: Number 2 is the key :)

Answer (score 0):

Add to your appsetting "xdt:Transform="Replace" attribute.
**Like below:**

```
  <appSettings xdt:Transform="Replace">
       <add  key="SMTPPort" value="58" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
  </appSettings>
```

It will replace whole appsettings with debug config.But if you don't want that you can apply that whatever tag you want. It will include all child elements of that tag.
By the way you should set attribute to configuration section also.I mark that below:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
```