# web.config, web.debug.config, web.release.config & Publish vs Debug?

Tags: c#, azure, web-config, transform

I've been trying to understand how to use the different config files and I just found [this link](http://www.tomot.de/en-us/article/5/asp.net/how-to-use-web.config-transforms-to-replace-appsettings-and-connectionstrings) which has been very helpful. The only problem is, that it seems the transforms only get taken into account when you 'publish' the solution and not if you just do a generic Debug or Run now.

Generally this wouldn't be to much of a problem, but I'm developing towards Windows Azure, which only allows you to publish to the Cloud. For general debugging I would rather run it locally within the Azure Emulator, but doing so does not 'process' my transforms.

Is there any known workaround to have them transformed during a debugging session?

Edit: ShawnC pointed me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350455/web-config-web-debug-config-web-release-config-publish-vs-debug#comment13334137_10350455) question.

Which lead me to [this](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) extension. I think this will do the job!

Comment: You could publish to your local IIS server.

Comment: Why/What do you want to transform? Couldn't you have development settings as a default and transform to production?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841075/web-config-transform-not-working/8841094#8841094

Answer (score 3):

You can perform web.config transforms using msbuild. You could put this in your project's AfterBuild target to aid your debugging.

You need to look at the `TransformXml` msbuild target, passing in: `Source=path_to_your/web.config`
`Transform=path_to_your/web.$(ConfigurationName).config`
and 
`Destination=path_to_your/web.config`