# Case insensitive match locator config transformation

Tags: c#, web-config, web.config-transform

I am transforming values of appsettings in web.config file depending on the environment. I ran into an issue when there are keys with same name but with different cases, example as below

Local Value

```
<add xdt:Transform="RemoveAll" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" key="LOGINURL" value="xyf" />
```

Dev Value

```
<add xdt:Transform="RemoveAll" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" key="LoginUrl" value="abcd" />
```

I would like to replace the value of keys case insensitively.

TIA

Answer (score 5):

You can use [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) with [the `Condition` locator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd465326(v=vs.110)#condition) instead of `Match`.
And using the hack described [here on building case insensitive matching in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39262011/361177) you may be able to write this:

```
<add xdt:Transform="RemoveAll" xdt:Locator= "Condition(translate(@key,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='loginurl')"/>
```

The `key` and `value` attribute are useless since the elements are removed.

To edit elements use `SetAttributes` to keep the keys untouched.

```
<add xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Condition(translate(@key,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='loginurl')" value="test.com" />
```

I tested all of it [here](https://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/).

Comment: I'm still looking on XPath2

Comment: This isn't working with Microsoft transformation DLL :(

Comment: @Chakri are you sure ? I tested it in VS2019, it works. Transformation are only visible while publishing see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841075. Please use the transformation preview (Right click on the Web.Debug.config file -> preview transformation).