# The "SourceRootPath" parameter is not supported by the "TransformXml" task

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, web.config-transform

In an ASP.NET project I'm getting the error while publishing

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1485,19):
Error MSB4064: The "SourceRootPath" parameter is not supported by the "TransformXml" task. 
Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.
```

What does it mean and what could cause it occur? I got it after migrating packages.config to PackageReference.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that this problem would only occur when there was a web.config transformation being done at **publish time**. Transformations at **build time** would not suffer from this error. [So I took the following steps to make the web.config transformation be done at build time.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69232853/1546844)